# Android reload fragments stack on restore

Tags: android, android-fragments

I’m developing an android application that makes heavy use of fragments, I’m running into an issue and I’ve been unable to find a solution so far.
The flow is this: the app is launched and MainActivity is the first responder, now, depending on user interaction several fragments gets loaded and pushed onto the stack.
Here is an example:

Main Activity -> fragment A -> fragment B -> fragment C -> etc..

Back history is enabled like so:

fragment C -> fragment B -> fragment A -> etc..

Everything works perfectly fine as long as my application is in foreground but everything breaks when the application goes in background.

If I’m on fragment B for example and I press the home button the application goes in background and when I restore it back it starts from MainActivity with fragment A.
Also, the toolbar shows the title of fragment B and, since fragment A contains a recyclerview I can see parts of fragment B between item rows, like a background image.

This is how I load fragments:

```
public void loadFragment(Fragment fragment, Boolean addToStack) {

    // Load fragment
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

    // show back button
    if (addToStack) {

        // Code to show the back button.
    }
    else if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 && !addToStack) {

        hideBackButton();

        fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    }

    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

I call this function from MainActivity and from the fragments:

```
MyFragment theFragment = new MyFragment();
MainActivity.instance.loadFragment(theFragment, true);
```

What I want to achieve is that when the application is restored it gets straight to the previously loaded fragment, keeping the entire "back" history. How can I do this?

I'm not sure if other portions of code are needed, but if so I'll post them as required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so, after a lot of research I found the issue… and the issue was a mistake of mine.

I’d like to report it here for everyone that might run into the same issue.

At first I tried to force fragment replacement on onResume() function like so:

```
Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, f);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

However android should handle all of this automatically, at least in my knowledge, and so I tried to dig further and I finally narrowed it down to my onStart() method.
Basically I was registering the EventBus and making a function call

```
if (!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)) {

    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);

    UserNetworkManager userNetworkManager = new UserNetworkManager(MainActivity.mainActivity);
    userNetworkManager.fetchFeed();
}
```

This code was creating the issue and after all it was not necessary to put it there, so I moved it to the onCreate() method, cleaned up my code a little bit and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

call the onResume() function:

```
public void onResume(){
    Fragment frg = null;
    frg = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Your_Fragment_TAG");
    final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.detach(frg);
    ft.attach(frg);
    ft.commit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however I'm not able to make it work. On my fragment's onResume I have no access to getSupportFragmentManager(). I also tried getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag_here") and getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag_here") but they both return null everytime. Can you please tell me more about your approach?